# What does DECODE-UNIVERSAL-TIME do in half-hour time zones?

Tags: timezone, common-lisp

In Common Lisp, the `decode-universal-time` function returns several values, one of which is the time zone in hours. What does this time zone contain in time zones that are half an hour off from surrounding time zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of hours specifying [time zone](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_t.htm#time_zone) is *not* necessarily an `integer`:

> time zone n. a rational multiple of 1/3600 between -24 (inclusive) and 24 (inclusive) that represents a time zone as a number of hours offset from Greenwich Mean Time...

IOW, the precision is a *second*. Thus, the time zone of, say, [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) is `-11/2` (i.e., [UTC+05:30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B05:30))

PS. I believe `rational` in "*rational multiple of 1/3600*" above should be `integer`. It's a typo.

Comment: Not sure why you think it is a typo; I read it as: the time zone can be a rational R satisfying `(<= -24 R 24)`, such that R equals `(* N 1/3600)` for some integer N; it is rational which must be a multiple of 1/3600, hence "rational multiple".

Comment: @coredump: I interpret "rational multiple of X" as "rational number times X". You interpret it as "a rational number which is an integer times X".

Comment: It seems that your interpretation is the most commonly used one (e.g. in trigonometry, with rational multiples of pi, etc.). Note however that in the glossary, *rational* is a link, which is why I think the authors intended to describe the type of the value, like with other entries (i.e. *time zone, a rational, is a multiple of ...*). It is unfortunate that both words are put next to each other like so without a comma, but I think there is an implicit separation between those words. Sorry for discussing this detail, I should probably be doing other things.